# can I make the array containing 5 names display Vertically Using the stylesheet in react native??

Tags: react-native

```
render() {
var myloop = [
      "Karan " + "\n",
      "bharat " + "\n",
      "parth " + "\n",
      "dharmil " + "\n",
      "raj "
    ];
return(
<Text>{myloop}</Text>
)
```

I know i can display it by using \n concatenation but i want to do it using stylesheet

Comment: Why would you do that? iterate over each entry and use div to assign new line.

Comment: @Justcode This is React Native, not the browser

Comment: yes this is react native and i want to put texts in new line using the stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help to you:

```
 var myloop = [
            "Karan ",
            "bharat",
            "parth",
            "dharmil",
            "raj"
        ];

        return (
            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
                <View>
                    {
                        myloop.map((value, index) => {
                            return <Text>{value}</Text>
                        })
                    }
                </View>
            </View>
        )
```